# Why is the iOS simulator printing $ instead of 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When I try to type 4 on a physical keyboard while running an iOS Simulator, it prints $ instead of 4.

How can I get the simulator to print 4?

Comment: I have not seen any reports of this; if you restart that simulator does it still happen?

Comment: @russbishop Yeah, this has been happening for me on all simulators across simulator reboot, mac reboot and it got worse after I updated XCode to 10.0, so I was seeing the same issue in XCode 9+.

Comment: @russbishop ...and it's not just me. Others at my office have the same issue while working on a different project than I was.

Comment: @russbishop I just tested on 2 active projects again. UITextFields subclassed and default, both with Text Input Traits and all default. I also tried "typing" using MacOS' on-screen-keyboard in the "Show Keyboard Viewer" instead of using the hardware keyboard, but in all these cases the UITextFields always type "$" instead of "4"

Comment: @russbishop Ah, I see. The fact that you hadn't heard of it, and the fact that we see it a lot, meant I suspect I've found the issue. It's because we're using the Danish hardware and MacOS keyboard settings. If I change the keyboard to "English UK" the simulator types "4", but if I switch to "Danish", it types "$"

Comment: Oh, can you file a bug report with that? https://bugreport.apple.com. Probably something in the keyboard map.

Comment: @russbishop Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an iOS Xcode bug, where in past versions of Xcode, I only noticed this issue on some UITextFields which were marked as "password", and sometimes requiring more parameters than just "password".

In the XCode versions (10.0 and 10.1), I'm seeing this issue constantly regardless of which parameters I set on the TextField.

The only way I can type 4 in a simulator using a physical keyboard, is to press ctrl-3, which prints 4.

To print: "2345", I therefore have to press "2 3 ctrl-3 5"

EDIT:
The issue seems to be with the "Danish" keyboard. Both a physical keyboard and the MacOS on-screen keyboard will now write "$" in the simulator when typing "4".
If you switch the language to i.e. "English UK", the simulator will correctly type "4".